# How to remove the hash # when the base URL is not root?

Tags: vue-router, vuejs2

I'm trying to serve a SPA where the path is not the root. e.g. `/login`

By default Vue-router will change the URL to `/login#/` and render the page as normal.

If I add `mode: 'history'` to my router, to prevent the hash from appearing, it will not render the component.

I'm using Bottlepy to serve the application when I load up http://localhost:8080/login. I've also tried using `/login/` which will make it `/login/#/`. But adding `mode: 'history'` still won't render the component.

index.html

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><router-link to="/">Home</router-link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">

      <router-view></router-view>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Template

```
<template id="login">
  <div>
    <p>Hello Login</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script

```
<script>
var LoginComponent = Vue.extend({
    template: '#login'
  });


// Define routes
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: LoginComponent }
]

// Create the router instance and pass the `routes` option
const router = new VueRouter({ routes: routes, mode: 'history' })

// Create and mount the root instance.
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')

// Now the app has started!
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using, vue-cli with webpack 2, to slove that.

`npm i -g vue-cli`

`vue init webpack`

When you init app, you can choise using vue-router

edit vue-router : `mode: 'history'`

Serve local app :

`npm start`